# What should I change to save the new sheet as (Value in A2)+text?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create an automatic Excel file when I enter a name in the cell A2. I also want to have common name after A2 value to all the files created. Let's say "Apple" is in A2, I want the sheet to be saved as "Apple date.xlsx".

Please Help.

```vb
Public Sub newFile()
    'Save "file 2" as new workbook with student name from File1
    
    'Set a variable for the file name (INCLUDING PATH) to File2
    Dim File2 As String: File2 = "C:\test\File2.xlsx"
    
    'Set a variable for the path the folder you want to save the new file in.
    Dim NewFilePath As String: NewFilePath = "C:\Test_New\"
    
    'Set the cell with the name you want the new file to have. Replace "Sheet1" and "A2" with the appropriate worksheet/cell
    Dim NewFileName As String: NewFileName = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value
    
    'Save Workbook and disable alerts so the new file saves without pop-ups opening
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=File2
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=NewFilePath & NewFileName & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
End Sub
```

Answer (score -2):

Dim NewFileName As String: NewFileName = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value & " Text"

Comment: Is this supposed to be an answer or an update to your question? In the former case, please read [answer] and then improve it. In the latter case, please edit your question instead.